# Looking for a software that allows to add translation manually, manage several languages and to save/export file format / extension yaml

Tags: open-source, translation

I'm developing a project that requires support for multiple languages: English; Spanish, French, Portuguese, German, Russian, Mandarin, Hindi, Arabic, Bengali, Indonesian.

The general indication is that the language strings should be stored in files: CSV, JSON or YAML; preferably YAML.

Project Link: https://fnd.us/61yKK2?ref=sh_8B9O71

**I need help or suggestions:**

1. What I can't find is an Open Source software that allows me to write the translation for each key in a friendly way; since the translation must be done by native linguistic people (not A.I. or services).
2. What is expected is the YAML translation file, there should be some mechanism to convert the final file to YAML or save/export it on this format to be implement by development like dictionaries for the project.

**Software preferences:**

3. It should have multi-platform operating system support (Linux, Windows).

The closest thing to software with this feature is when OpenOffice Calc opens a CSV file (UTF-8 separated by semicolons); but I am looking for something to work with YAML files.

[image]

**Update**

I haven't found any software that exports dictionaries to yaml; but if I have found one similar to open calc (it has a grid that allows me to see all the languages to be translated) it includes the translation service although this is not necessary, since the translation would be done manually.

*the program is BabelEdit; now the problem is that it is a monthly payment and the quota is limited for trial accounts and it expires; I'll keep looking for something free*

[image]

Comment: not update for it at this moment ...